# Code style Java: bubbling up return value from private method

Tags: java

I often face the situation where I want to do some calculations in a private method and bubble up the return of the private method when it is not null. I feel there should be a nicer way than doing this:

```
public String myMethod(int value) {
    String tmp = strategy1(value);
    if (tmp != null) {
        return tmp;
    }
    tmp = strategy2(value)
    if (tmp != null) {
        return tmp;
    }
    return "default result"
}

private String strategy1(int value) {
    return value > 1? "Good value" : null;
}
```

What I would like to write is something like this (not working java code)

```
public String myMethod(int value) {
    return if(strategy1(value) != null);
    return if(strategy2(value) != null);
    return "default result"
}
```

any best practice to achieve this nicely?

Comment: or just return a bool from your `assertStuff` method.. then you can `if(!assertStuff(value)) //doFailureThings else \\doNonFailureThings`

Comment: maybe assert is not the best wording in that case. The private method should actually produce some value that I want to bubble up if it is there

Comment: Are you looking for an `Optional`?

Comment: Can you give an example? I thought about using an optional, too. My idea was that: `calcStuff().ifPresent(str -> return str));` but the return is not possible there.

Comment: `if(strategy1(value) != null) return ""; if(strategy2(value)) return ""; return "default";` is perfectly valid Java code. What you edited in is possible with a small tweak.

Comment: @VinceEmigh that's exactly my problem. I want the value of my computation to be returned where you wrote "" without executing it again :). I guess there is just no better way in java to write that without a temp variable.

Comment: @A1m The value of what computation? You want to return `myMethod` so whoever called it can call it again at a later time?

Answer (score 1):

If you need to check `value` passed to method you rather need to throw exception than return `null` values, return `null`s is a bad practise. Read about it in *Effective Java*. Consider this, your code should be something like that:

```
 public String myMethod(int value) {
        if (value < 1) { 
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        }
 }
```

if you try to validate something, you would be better return boolean than make deal with null and check it outside code that do it work.

```
public boolean isValid(int value) {
           return (value > 1);
}
```

Even better approach is create interface `Value`

```
interface Value<T> {

     boolean isValid();

     T getValue() throws IllegalStateException;

}
```

that incapsulate certain value and return `true` when value is good and `false` when it is bad, when you try to get value that bad it throws exception;

Comment: I wouldn't say the `Value` interface would be a better approach, quite an overkill. IMO, if you had a `Value` interface, it would be better to expose declarative alternative: `value.ifValid(realValue -> ...)`, similar to `Optional#isPresent`. But +1 for suggesting exceptions for invalid input, keeps it OOP rather than use the procedural way of returning a `boolean` if the method did not execute properly.

Comment: I actually never want `myMethod` to return null. I just want to do subcalculations in private methods and if they yield a result return that, if not go ahead. This always creates more boilerplate for me.

Comment: @A1m What do you mean "go ahead"? If you have a method that returns a value, it can't just "go ahead", it needs to return a value. You may want something more declarative, such as I showed in the comment above: `processValue(myMethod(), value -> ...)`, which only invokes the callback if the value is present, and "does nothing" if the value isn't present. But really, it seems like you want `Optional`: `Optional<String> value = Optional.of(myMethod());` so you could then do `value.ifPresent(string -> ...)`

Comment: @A1m Your example to abstract to give you certain answer, it will be better to place some real code.

Answer (score 0):

If your strategies were implementations of a "Strategy" interface, then you could use a utility method like this:

```
public interface Strategy {
    String evaluate(int);
}

public String firstResult(int candidate, String defaultValue, Strategy... strategies) {
    for (Strategy strategy : strategies) {
        String result=strategy.evaluate(candidate);
        if (result!=null) return result;
    }
    return defaultValue;
}
```

Using an interface allows you to support short-circuiting-- after the first strategy returns a non-null result, none of the other strategies are processed.

Java 8 Usage:

```
    System.out.println(firstResult(12, "snot-nosed kid",
            age -> age >= 18 ? "adult" : null,
            age -> age > 12 ? "teen" : null,
            age -> age < 5 ? "pre-school" : null
    ));
```

Java 7 Usage:

```
    Strategy strategy1=new Strategy() {
        public String evaluate(int candidate) {
            return candidate >=18 ? "adult" : null;
        }
    };
    Strategy strategy2=new Strategy() {
        public String evaluate(int candidate) {
            return candidate >12 ? "teen" : null;
        }
    };
    Strategy strategy3=new Strategy() {
        public String evaluate(int candidate) {
            return candidate < 5 ? "pre-school" : null;
        }
    };

    System.out.println(firstResult(12, "snot-nosed kid", strategy1, strategy2, strategy3));
```